# Book in which a girl was transported back in time whenever she put on a red anorak

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

There was this book I read in the early 90's, but I don't know when the actual book was published.

The only thing I can remember plot-wise is that every time this girl put on a red anorak, she was transported back in time to this Druid era. I literally remember nothing else, except maybe she moved from the city to the country?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [*An Acceptable Time*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0374300275) by Madeleine L'Engle (part of the Wrinkle in Time quintet)?

> A flash of lightning, quivering ground, and, instead of her
> grandparents' farm, Polly sees mist and jagged mountains -- and coming
> toward her, a group of young men carrying spears.
>
> Why has a time gate opened and dropped Polly into a world that existed
> 3,000 years ago? Will she be able to get back to the present before
> the time gate closes -- and leaves her to face a group of people who
> believe in human sacrifice?

The main character wears a red anorak. She goes back to the time of the druids. Oh, and she's just moved home.

> [image]